# Ip telephone being not served by DHCP

Tags: juniper, telephony, srx

I have a DHCP configured on juniper router srx345  and an external DHCP runing on win machine and configured by telephony ppl.

I'm using an IP tel Astra i740N when I send  DHCP request to DHCP server  being run localy on srx345 the DHCP  replies to back to 10.3.85.12 which is not existing or is not being handed yet.

```
{root@srx-rad% tcpdump -n -i reth0.2085
15:20:03.584348  In IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:08:5d:1d:67:e9, length 548
15:20:03.849730 Out IP truncated-ip - 247 bytes missing! 10.3.85.1.67 > 10.3.85.12.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 269
15:21:22.687841  In IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:08:5d:1d:67:e9, length 548
15:21:22.688052 Out IP truncated-ip - 247 bytes missing! 10.3.85.1.67 > 10.3.85.12.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 269
15:21:37.687720  In IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:08:5d:1d:67:e9, length 548
15:21:37.687840 Out IP truncated-ip - 247 bytes missing! 10.3.85.1.67 > 10.3.85.12.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 26
}

{primary:node0}
rtomecek@srx-rad> show arp | match 10.3.85.

{primary:node0}
rtomecek@srx-rad> show dhcp server binding    

DHCP POOL
{set routing-instances GLOBAL access address-assignment pool TEST_Wifi_v2084 family inet dhcp-attributes router 10.3.84.1
set routing-instances GLOBAL access address-assignment pool TEST_VOIP_v2085 family inet dhcp-attributes grace-period 86400
set routing-instances GLOBAL access address-assignment pool TEST_VOIP_v2085 family inet dhcp-attributes router 10.3.85.1
set routing-instances GLOBAL access address-assignment pool TEST_VOIP_v2085 family inet dhcp-attributes boot-file 10.0.20.3 }
```

When I connect other type of a phone, SIP phone in particular, everything works fine.

Also when I have Astra i740N configured to send the DHCP requests to other DHCP server run on win machine  which is being configured for IP telephony, everything works.

So is there anything which needs to be further configured on the juniper srx for the IP telephony?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the device configurations. Otherwise, we're just guessing.

Comment: Hello, configuration on my devices is alright, I have just tested  another DHCP server which is running on windows machine and has specific config for serving  dhcp/bootp requests coming from  the IP tel Astra and it works fine.  So now I am trying to find what additional information does the  DHCP server running on the win machine has configured and are mising on the juniper 345.

Comment: That's a different question.  Please consider editing your question, or asking a different one.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your Call Server is `10.0.20.3`, then I think you've got a mistake in your configuration - you're referencing the TFTP Server IP address using `boot-file` instead of `boot-server`.  Try the following and see if it fixes your issue:

```
delete routing-instances GLOBAL access address-assignment pool TEST_VOIP_v2085 family inet dhcp-attributes boot-file 10.0.20.3
set routing-instances GLOBAL access address-assignment pool TEST_VOIP_v2085 family inet dhcp-attributes boot-server 10.0.20.3
```

Comment: I have tried the idea  with boot-server. It still behaves the same way.  But thx for the idea though.